# Many to many relationship SQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query that can fetch results in a many to many relationship database.
So far I got the following: 
One table with songs, one table with tags and a 'linking' table as one song can have multiple tags and one tag can belong to multiple songs.

it looks like this:

```
Songs       Link        Tags
=======     =====       =========
Sid          Sid        Tid
Songname     Tid        Tagname
```

Now suppose you have 3 songs A B and C and 3 tags: X, Y and Z. 
Song A has tag Y, song B has tag Z, and song C has tag X and Z.

I've managed to create a query to get a song by just one tag (e.g. Z gives B and C).
But how do i create a query that searches for songs when mutiple tags are enterred (e.g. typed into a (search) field). 
I've searched and a few times the commands INTERSECT and INNER JOIN came up, but i havent been able to succesfully create a query.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you want songs that match **any** or **all** of the given Tags?

Comment: For now only that match all tags, but perhaps some ranking as in these hit 2/2 and these 1/2 later on ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one will get all songs, that match **any** of the Tags, returning those which match all of them first:

```
SELECT s.Sid, s.Songname
FROM Songs s
JOIN Link l ON ( l.Sid = s.Sid )
JOIN Tags t ON ( t.Tid = s.Tid )
WHERE t.Tagname IN ( 'X', 'Y' )
GROUP BY s.Sid, s.Songname
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

---

This one will only return those songs, that match **all** of the Tags:

```
SELECT s.Sid, s.Songname
FROM Songs s
JOIN Link l ON ( l.Sid = s.Sid )
JOIN Tags t ON ( t.Tid = s.Tid )
WHERE t.Tagname IN ( 'X', 'Y' )
GROUP BY s.Sid, s.Songname
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2 -- 'X' and 'Y'
```

If you generate this query, you will have to generate the count too (`2` in my case).

Comment: But what if there are songs with more than 2 tags added later on, and you want dynamically to filter only that hit all/all?

Comment: You will have to generate the `IN`-list from the input, and you will have to generate the count too - last sentence in my answer (hope I got your question right).

Comment: Nevermind thought of a solution to it. just use php to retrieve all tags, and then use the count(1) = length of array with tags :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'm gonna try all this

Comment: Hmm the second query with HAVING COUNT(1) = ... doesn't work. I created a query with 7 tags and it didn't hit, somehow the count(1) was 14. When i removed the HAVING part it worked, but that created the first query-like effect

Comment: Do you have the same tag assigned more than once? What happens when you try `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.Tagname) = 7`?

Comment: Let me try that... but no i recently asked a query to fill the database without getting doubles and that works :)

Comment: Right it did the job.. apparently i entered a tag wrong (typo) and that caused some problems, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's your basic many to many select statement.

```
select s.*, t.*  
from songs s
join songs_tags st on s.songId = st.songId
join tags t on t.tagId = st.tagId
-- optional where clause
where s.name = 'my song'
```

When the where clause is tag based, flip it around

```
select s.*, t.*  
from tags t
join songs_tags st on s.songId = st.songId
join songs s on s.songId = st.songId
-- optional where clause
where t.name = 'whatever'
```

If you want to return all songs with multiple tags, simply change the where clause:

```
select s.*
from tags t
join songs_tags st on s.songId = st.songId
join songs s on s.songId = st.songId
where t.name in ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')
```

Returning a specific song with specific tags, for example, if you wanted to search by name and tag

```
select s.*, t.*  
from songs s
join songs_tags st on s.songId = st.songId
join tags t on t.tagId = st.tagId
where s.name like '%mysong%' and t.name in ('tag1', 'tag2')
```

You can also filter the join tables themselves and is sometimes necessary:

```
select s.*, t.*  
from songs s
join songs_tags st on s.songId = st.songId
join tags t on t.tagId = st.tagId and t.name in ('tag1', 'tag2')
where s.name like '%mysong%'
```

To find songs without a tag

```
select s.*
from songs s
left join songs_tags st on s.songId = st.songId
where st.songId is null
```

To find songs that have all tags:

```
select s.*
from songs s
join songs_tags st1 on s.songid = st1.songid
join songs_tags st2 on s.songid = st2.songid
join songs_tags st3 on s.songid = st3.songid
where st1.tagid = 1 and st2.tagid = 2 and st3.tagid = 3
```

Comment: The last statement doesn't seem to work. It finds a song if it has all three tag names in the same record. It never happens so the result will always be empty. The accepted answer is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.Sid, s.Songname 
FROM 
    Songs s join Link l on s.Sid=l.Sid 
    join Tags t on t.Tid=l.Tid 
WHERE t.Tagname in ('Z', 'Y');
```

This will return all songs that have EITHER tag Z or Y

Comment: And suppose i want the songs ONLY with tag Z AND Y? ^^ This query works great so far, but as i am learning you make me curious hehe

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct songs.* 
from songs 
inner join link on link.sid = songs.sid 
inner join tags on tags.tid = link.tid
where tagname IN ('a','b','c')
```

something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
select a.Sid, a.SongName, c.Tid, c.TagName  
from Songs a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Links b ON a.Sid = b.Sid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags c ON b.Tid = c.Tid 
WHERE c.TagName IN ('Tag1', 'Tag2', ...... ) // as many tags you want 
group by a.Sid, a.SongName, c.Tid, c.TagName
```